# How would you translate "Please enter the security code" into German?

Tags: english-to-german

I need these terms translated for a contact form that I am building for a German website.

- Please enter the security code
- Security Check
- Try another code
- Enter code

So far I have these terms that a friend helped me with.

**Please enter the security code**

```
Bitte den Sicherheitscode eingeben
```

**Security Check**

```
Sicherheitsüberprüfung
```

**Try another code**

```
Versuchen Sie einen anderen Code
```

That one seemed very long. Any other suggestions?

**Enter code**

```
 Code eingeben
```

Comment: Asking for translations is not appropriate on this Stack Exchange, as far as I know. Unless you're having specific problems with the translations (if you do, please edit your post), I don't think this question belongs here.

Comment: @clinch how is a translation not appropriate for a language site? I am looking at like 20 questions with a lot of upvotes that have to do with translation. And there was a tag for "english to german" translation. This unwelcoming attitude on Stack exchange is getting obnoxious. Please remove your downvote.

Comment: @JGallardo This is not a translation service. From this perspective, translations are off-topic. However, there's an easy way to make them on-topic which is you must show some prior research and/or attempts and clearly indicate why you failed. Note that many translations questions do not gain any up-votes at all, so try to make it better ;)

Comment: -1 I was thinking not to downvote this fully off-topic question because of, say, the first question tolerance; but then I saw "Please remove your downvote" and I couldn't avoid it.

Comment: The OP has a point when he writes that there have been many questions here recently which were not much better. They should have been closed.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz I tend to agree with you. However, there's at least one main difference between those you referring to and this one. This question only gives the English original sentence and says "Translate this for me". The other question at least show a translation attempt – admittedly most often a bad one. Those questions that even lack of an attempt **are closed**. As you see, it doesn't need much to make a question on-topic (although I still don't consider those on-topic, I just tolerate them). And if you'd add some real prior research, that shows why you failed, I'd even upvote. :)

Comment: @c.p. and leaving a comment like "perhaps you could show your previous research" would have went a long way. And that would have prompted me to improve as a user. As opposed to just downvoting and complaining that something should be closed.

Comment: @Em1 ok is that better? a friend sent me those through email but wanted to see how those compared. And which sounded more professional, thanks.

Comment: *sigh* Not better but more acceptable. As said, I tolerate those questions. For the future: actually you rather should come up with a particular problem like: "I'm having trouble translating the word 'x' in context 'y' because I don't think my translation 'z' sounds OK as my Internet search resulted in 'z' not being common, so I wonder how I can improve this sentence." Or something like this. I think you get the point. Still, we're neither a translations nor a proofreading service. - You're question is answered anyway.

Comment: I personally think that now that the translation attempts have been added this question should be reopened since as it was pointed out, quite a few questions in a similar form have received answers and not been closed. But, so does this mean that questions that ask for a translation with just an attempt at a translation will no longer be valid questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem in this question and I don't mind because as a native German it takes me one minute to answer this question.

- Please enter the security code

  > Bitte gib den Sicherheitscode ein.
- Security Check

  > Sicherheitskontrolle.
- Try another code

  > Bitte versuch es mit einem anderen Code.
- Enter code

  > Gib den Code ein.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have not been visiting many German sites in the last few years, but do they really use "Du" instead of "Sie"? What is the accepted tone of voice in web sites? `Geben Sie den Code ein.` or `Gib den Code ein.` --??

Comment: @teylyn.. I agree. I think the standard is still "Sie" unless the site is specifically targeted to people under 16. I think they avoid it for sites for the 20ish so as to not have them think the site is childish. That how it came across for me... not impolite but just childish.

Comment: Well I do see a problem in this question. Answering it  encourages more low quality questions by the same reason that the OP cannot believe that his question is not on topic (i.e. " I am looking at like 20 questions with a lot of upvotes that have to do with translation.") The point is that if somebody already answered questions that showed no effort, why should users bother to ask properly?

Comment: @c.p. what is the German translation for "Porque estas llorando tanto?"

Comment: this definitely helps. I was curious how "Sicherheitskontrolle" compares to "Sicherheitsüberprüfung" which is what a friend told me.

Comment: @JGallardo ... it means "Why are you crying so much". You got a proper answer fo' free. Let's just leave it at that.

Comment: @JGallardo Well, converting the question you posed into good Spanish (which means correcting four mistakes), you got a perfect translation by Emanuel. If you want the meaning in German, you need to open a new question ;)

Comment: @c.p. I actually posted a meta question some while ago on the topic of answering [translation requests with no effort whatsoever shown](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/494/is-it-welcome-to-answer-a-simple-translation-request)

Comment: Is this a cultural thing? because if you were to ask any Spanish speaker how to say something, we would be happy to help you out.